# How to set a button to most right side of navigation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I set a button to right side of navigation bar:

[image]

I want to set a burger icon,red cycle and a label  to this button. like this:

[image]

my code:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = self.utilities.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#00b8de")

    var imageview2 = UIImage(named: "menulogo")

    imageview2 = imageview2?.imageResize(sizeChange: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))

    btnMenu.setImage(imageview2,for:UIControlState.normal)
    btnMenu.setTitle("", for: .normal)


    // setup the red circle UIView
    let redCircleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    redCircleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    redCircleView.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width / 2

    // setup the number UILabel
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    label.text = "16"

    // adding the label into the red circle
    redCircleView.addSubview(label)

    // adding the red circle into the menu button
    btnMenu.addSubview(redCircleView)
```

with above codes I have three problems:

1. my burger image isn't in most right side of navigation.
2. my cycle view doesn't show
3. my icon is white, but it shows blue!

[image]

Comment: One question: what is `btnMenu`? It's not initialized in your code snippet.

Comment: it's my button inside navigation as you can see in image.